# How to connect ethereum smart contract with iOS app

Tags: swift, ethereum, solidity

I want to connect smart contract with iOS app using webView. I researched so many  but didn't get any thing. How to call smart contract from the iOS using swift.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using webView, then you should be able to use web3js and connect to a smart contract by...

1. Connecting to network via. HttpProvider:
   (`new web3.providers.HttpProvider('<ADDRESS-TO-NETWORK>')`)
2. Connecting to the contract:
   (`web3.eth.Contract('<CONTRACT-ABI>', '<CONTRACT-ADDRESS>')`)

...but you will also have to deal with making sure there is also an available Ethereum account to complete these transactions.

The web3 documentation isn't the best but you can find what you need under accounts and contracts: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html

Comment: What is ADDRESS-TO-NETWORK? Is it rpc port

Comment: @DivyaGalla It's the network address you are connecting to that is running an ethereum client. If you have a server running it, you can use your own exposed address here: `HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545/')`. Most people, and in this case, you'd run a connection through Infura, so I'd look something like this: `HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/<KEY>')`

Comment: what is 8545 is it rpcport? we give when we tried to establish Ethereum Private Network?

Comment: I gave different for each node in private network and my client side Eg; Android should interact with the private network, not with the individual node.Then how is it possible

Comment: How would you call a function of a specific smart contract?